# Menu transition in websites CSS

Tags: html, css, transition

I have started wokring on the template http://irontemplates.com/wp-demos/lush-classical/     I recently saw the site http://beeshoney.jp/culture/. I would like to achieve the menu transition as this. I am a beginner to web designing. Kindly help me to understand the concept and get it done. Please.

In my template: they have used right property and in the one I saw they have used translate property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use animation keyframes

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
body{height: 100%}
menu{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #333;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center
}
menu li{
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
menu li:first-child{
  -webkit-animation: translateIntro .3s .1s ease forwards
}
menu li:nth-child(2){
  -webkit-animation: translateIntro .3s .2s ease forwards
}
menu li:nth-child(3){
  -webkit-animation: translateIntro .3s .3s ease forwards
}
menu li:nth-child(4){
  -webkit-animation: translateIntro .3s .4s ease forwards
}
menu li:last-child{
  -webkit-animation: translateIntro .3s .5s ease forwards
}
@-webkit-keyframes translateIntro {
  to{opacity: 1;transform: translateX(0%)}
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Pricing</li>
  <li>Work</li>
  <li>Lab</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thank You.. I ll check an d tell tq:)